# Cocoa interface: 2d slider

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder

I am looking for a 2D slider in Cocoa.

It should be something similar to this:

[image: a busy cat]
<sub>(source: [wolfram.com](https://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Files/Slider2D.en/O_1.gif))</sub>

which is Mathematica's 2D slider [look here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Slider2D.html). It seems that there is nothing like this in Xcode interface builder.

Basically my cocoa interface should show a room seen from above (the space where the 2d slider can move), and when I click on it, the 2D cursor moves to that location in the room.
Any ideas on how to do this?

An easy way would be to have 2 orthogonal 1D slider, but it's not a nice looking solution.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The really simple way: subclass NSView, and use the [Three-Method Approach](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/HandlingMouseEvents/HandlingMouseEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH6-SW3) to mouse event handling to record the current point (converted to whatever coordinate space you choose, such as 0,0 at the center). In [-drawRect:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html), draw your intersecting lines and "knob" (either directly or by drawing a pre-rendered "knob.png" image, for example). Since [NSView](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html) inherits from [NSResponder](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSResponder), you can use the [target/action](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH7-SW14) mechanism to notify your controller when the view's value changed due to a click or knob-drag.

Comment: Thanks @Joshua! I am now working on that. Unfortunately, I am struggling a little with the target/action mechanism. Can you possibly have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8424898/mouse-event-which-instance-is-which-objective-c) question I posted? Thanks!