# Mouse event: which instance is which? (Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c, mouseevent

I am learning objective-C, and I need to handle a mouse down event.

My header is something like:

```
@interface TestAppDelegate : NSWindow <NSWindowDelegate> {
  NSWindow *window;
  IBOutlet NSTextField* text_box;
}
```

while the implementation file is:

```
-(void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)event {
  [text_box setFloatValue:1.0];
  NSLog(@"It worked!");
}

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification{
  [text_box setFloatValue:-1.0];
}
```

and the interface has only an text field connected to my `text_box`. In the xib file I set the class name to `TestAppDelegate`.

Now, the mouse down event seems to work, as I can see the "It worked!" log. However, the text box is not updated, and stays `-1`.

To understand what is happening, I added a button which is linked to

```
-(IBAction)scrollerChanged:(id)sender {
  [text_box setFloatValue:2.0];
}
```

and this correctly updates my `text_form` to `2`. Hence, my interpretations is that the mouse down event is calling a different instance of TestAppDelegate. Am I right? Am I doing something fundamentally wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does look like you’ve actually got multiple instances of `TestAppDelegate`. (It’s a little unusual to have an `NSWindow` object also be it’s own delegate *and* the app delegate).

Just guessing, you might have an `NSWindow` in your xib that you’ve set the class to `TestAppDelegate`, and another generic `NSObject` object in the xib that also is set to your `TestAppDelegate` class.

You’ve probably linked `text_box` to just one of your instances (probably the app delegate `NSObject` one), while your `NSWindow` instance is the one that actually receives the `mouseDown:` event.